# Instagram image posting with UIDocumentInteractionController

Tags: ios, cocoa, crop, instagram

I am using UIDocumentInteractionController to post images to Instagram iOS App and it is working well. But, when the image appear in Instagram, it is not possible to crop it. The first cropping step is skipped. I tried to post "non squared" images but the cropping is still impossible.

Is there a way to post images to Instagram App and allow the user to crop it like other imported images?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's possible right now.

Libraries like [DMActivityInstagram](https://github.com/coryalder/DMActivityInstagram) include a resize viewcontroller of their own to cope with this.